# Remove root / from S3 cloudfront static website redirect

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a static S3 website that just points to a different domain: `https://www.externaldomain.com/id12345`

This S3 is assigned to a CloudFront which is then assigned to A record to `mydomain.com`

The result is that when I navigate to `mydomain.com` it redirects visitors to `https://www.externaldomain.com/id12345`

Everything works fine, except it redirects to `https://www.externaldomain.com/id12345/` with the **/** at the end

How can I make it redirect to exactly `https://www.externaldomain.com/id12345` without the **/**

I do not have control over the `externaldomain.com` and it gives 404 when **/** is included.

Comment: How, exactly, did you configure the bucket to redirect?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot created a bucket and set it to static hosting -> "Redirect requests" -> www.externaldomain.com/id12345 (without **/** at the end) and Protocol "https"

Comment: Also tried adding `index.html` with a javascript redirect inside, it still adds trailing slash. I've read about creating S3 object called `/id12345/` and adding header `x-amz-website-redirect-location` with `/id123456` as value. That does not seem to work. It doesn't find such header and it is not been added after save. S3 object is just a folder right?

Comment: There must be a very simple solution to this, I am just not savvy with AWS S3

Comment: What's happening, here, is that S3 is trying to preserve the request path.  If you go to `your-bucket/foo` the redirection will to to `example.com/12345/foo`, so this behavior, while at first confusing, does make sense.  I can provide an alternate configuration, but I need to know if you want to preserve the path, or if you want all requests, regardless of the original path, to go to just `/12345` at the new site.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot all requests, regardless of the original path

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you select the option to redirect all requests to another host, S3 assumes you want to preserve the original request path at the end of the new URL.  Request URIs always begin with `/`, so when S3 appends the incoming request URI onto the path you provided when generating the redirect, there's the `/` from your request at the end.  It's not so much that S3 is *adding* it, as that it is *copying* it from the incoming request URI.

So the behavior is confusing at first glance, but not incorrect.

What you stated in comments that you want to do is, regardless of the path, throw it away.  All requests go to a single path on the destination service.

For this, use a routing rule.  Select "Use this bucket to host a web site" and then make up a name for an Index Document -- you don't actually need one for this use-case, but the field is not optional, so just enter `index.html`.  Then, add a redirection rule that looks like this:

```xml
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <KeyPrefixEquals></KeyPrefixEquals> <!-- empty string matches all requests -->
     </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <Protocol>https</Protocol>
        <HostName>other-site.example.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyWith>12345</ReplaceKeyWith> <!-- new path, with *no* leading slash -->
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

See [Advanced Conditional Redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects) in the S3 Developer Guide for more about the routing rule syntax.

The documentation doesn't mention using an empty `<KeyPrefixEquals>` to match all requests, but this works because what you're asking the rule to test is (pseudocode) `left(key,0) == ''`, which of course is always true.

Also not explicit is the fact that S3 object keys, by convention, do not start with `/` (the leading `/` used in HTTP is, conceptually, *before* the first character of the object key).  This is why `<ReplaceKeyWith>` and any other key reference doesn't need (and shouldn't have) a leading `/` in redirect routing rules.

---

Best practice suggests you ignore the following alternative solution, presented for your consideration. It is horrible, hacky, and wrong in so many ways, but it should work for many applications...

Use the "Redirect requests" option, as you originally were doing, but put `#` at the end of the path you provide.  Then S3 redirects to `https://example.com/12345#/` or, more precisely, `https://example.com/12345#${original_uri}`.  Because `#` marks the beginning of the URI Fragment, it isn't sent to the destination server, so it should do what you want, too, though it may interact with an SPA router, if that's what you're using.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thank you for the detailed explanation too!

Comment: AWS no longer supports XML.  See my answer below for the JSON version.  The moderators rejected my edit to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer above uses XML, which is no longer supported. Here is the answer using JSON, which AWS requires nowadays.  I tried to edit the accepted answer, but the moderators [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27886927) my edit as changing the intent of the original author.  Go figure.

When you select the option to redirect all requests to another host, S3 assumes you want to preserve the original request path at the end of the new URL. Request URIs always begin with /, so when S3 appends the incoming request URI onto the path you provided when generating the redirect, there's the / from your request at the end. It's not so much that S3 is adding it, as that it is copying it from the incoming request URI.

So the behavior is confusing at first glance, but not incorrect.

What you stated in comments that you want to do is, regardless of the path, throw it away. All requests go to a single path on the destination service.

For this, use a routing rule. Select *Use this bucket to host a web site* and then make up a name for an Index Document -- you don't actually need one for this use-case, but the field is not optional, so just enter index.html. Then, add a redirection rule that looks like this:

```json
    [
        {
            "Condition": {
                "KeyPrefixEquals": ""
            },
            "Redirect": {
                "HostName": "www.externaldomain.com",
                "Protocol": "https",
                "ReplaceKeyWith": "id12345"
            }
        }
    ]
```

See [Advanced Conditional Redirects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html#advanced-conditional-redirects) in the S3 Developer Guide for more about the routing rule syntax.

The documentation doesn't mention using an empty *KeyPrefixEquals* to match all requests, but this works because what you're asking the rule to test is *(pseudocode) left(key,0) == ''*, which of course is always true.

Also not explicit is the fact that S3 object keys, by convention, do not start with / (the leading / used in HTTP is, conceptually, before the first character of the object key). This is why *ReplaceKeyWith* and any other key reference doesn't need (and shouldn't have) a leading / in redirect routing rules.

Best practice suggests you ignore the following alternative solution, presented for your consideration. It is horrible, hacky, and wrong in so many ways, but it should work for many applications...

Use the "Redirect requests" option, as you originally were doing, but put # at the end of the path you provide. Then S3 redirects to `https://externaldomain.com/id12345#/` or, more precisely, `https://externaldomain.com/id12345#${original_uri}`. Because # marks the beginning of the URI Fragment, it isn't sent to the destination server, so it should do what you want, too, though it may interact with an SPA router, if that's what you're using.

Comment: The correct action to take in this case would have been to comment on the original answer with a docs citation for the change, or create your own answer but without copying the entire text of my answer into your own.  The AWS console, it appears, has indeed changed from XML to JSON which is intuitively a really bizarre thing for them to have done, so it makes sense to me that the edits were rejected by the community. Still, I will research it and update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Making a comment to your original answer would not have given users the necessary formatted code they need.  If you found my answer useful, please upvote it to help others.